Перевод других сайтов сети Stack Exchange
Возможен ли перевод других сайтов сети на русский и другие языки?
К примеру AI, MSE или допустим Mathematics.
Почему на русский и другие языки был переведён только SO, а другие не менее полезные сайты не были перевидены? Почему бы не перевести их?
